# When user makes a commit in SVN, which file always gets modified?

Tags: svn, repository

When a user makes a commit in an SVN repository, which file always gets modified by SVN?

For example:

1. `user` creates `xyz` repository.
2. `user` does a checkout of `xyz`.
3. `user` makes a commit.

Now I want to know which file will get modified in the master `xyz` repository?

Comment: It depends on repository backend and possibly the changes the revision you commit contains. As of FSFS backend, you might want to read https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_fs_fs/structure

Comment: is there any way to check last commit time from master repository ?

Comment: Read the documentation: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/index.html the command is `svn info URL` and it has nothing to do with the original question.